# JOINing multiple tables properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show all payments that are of `payment_type` **credit**. I am, however, only seeing one and my `total` column is definitely not right. I must be screwing up my `JOINs` but I don't know how to fix them. I have tried different combos of `LEFTs` `RIGHTs` etc and keep coming up short.

I should be seeing `Tammy` and `Terry`. The total is currently right.

Here is a [fiddle of my SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e07d/1).

Also, my query here:

```
SELECT p.conf, 
       Concat(g.fname, ' ', g.lname) AS guest, 
       u.unit_name, 
       p.card_type, 
       p.payment_amt, 
       Sum(p.payment_amt)            AS total 
FROM   payments p, 
       guests g, 
       units u, 
       reservations r 
WHERE  p.reservation = r.id 
       AND r.guest = g.id 
       AND r.unit = u.id 
       AND p.payment_date = '2013-11-01' 
       AND p.payment_type = 'credit'
```

Comment: Show us what your desired output is. You say you want both Tammy and Terry to appear, but you want the total of both of them combined?

Comment: Yes, the total is correct for their `SUM`. I just am not getting the other `guest` to display.

Comment: Yes but I don't understand (and can't predict) what your desired output is. Do you want 2 rows that show `Tammy 603` and `Terry 603`? (+ the other columns)

Comment: For this example, yes. Sorry, I wasn't thinking about that. I am using this query to place into a PDF and so am only **using** the total once.

Comment: accidental. Thanks for pointing it out. His was very helpful, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well you can do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT p.conf, 
       Concat(g.fname, ' ', g.lname) AS guest, 
       u.unit_name, 
       p.card_type, 
       p.payment_amt,
       ( SELECT SUM(payment_amt) 
         FROM payments 
         WHERE payment_date = p.payment_date 
           AND payment_type = p.payment_type) AS total
FROM payments p 
LEFT JOIN reservations r ON p.reservation = r.id 
LEFT JOIN guests g ON r.guest = g.id 
LEFT JOIN units u ON  r.unit = u.id 
WHERE p.payment_date = '2013-11-01' 
  AND p.payment_type = 'credit'
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e07d/19/0)

Alternatively you could just calculate the total afterwards, and UNION it to the rest of the results:

```
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'Total', NULL, NULL, SUM(payment_amt) 
FROM payments 
WHERE payment_date = '2013-11-01' 
  AND payment_type = 'credit'
```

Full SQL on [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e07d/29/0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add GROUP BY like this:

```
GROUP BY g.fname, g.lname
```

See [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e07d/31)